# Collecting data

Tags: python

I am not sure if this is possible but I am dealing with datetime in python so I know it can get confusing.

I have a python script that runs every 5 mins and collects data between 5mins and 3 mins. This is working fine if the script runs on 00 seconds

I am not sure if this is possible but I am dealing with datetime in python so I know it can get confusing.

I have a python script that runs every 5 mins and collects data between 5mins and 3 mins. This is working fine if the script runs on 00 seconds

Comment: `This is working fine if the script runs bang on 00 seconds` what does this mean ?

Comment: look at the example below, if the script runs on the 00 seconds. i put examples below to help

Answer (score 0):

Create a conditional statement that checks whether the time ends with '00', using the [the Timer function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) to run code every second. Then when the time is how you want it, execute your code.

Comment: are you able to show me because i am struggling on this alot.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is use modulo the interval I'm interested in, so 15 minutes in your case:

```
>>> t = time.time()
>>> t
1555065206.8165069
>>> t += 15*60-1
>>> t -= t % (15*60)
>>> t
1555065900.0
>>> time.localtime(t)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=12, tm_hour=12, tm_min=45, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=102, tm_isdst=1)
```

So what you could do is something like:

```
import time

while True:
    t = time.time()
    t += 15*60-1
    t -= t % (15*60)
    print(time.localtime(t))
    print('printing again in 5 minutes')
    time.sleep(5*60)
```

That should output something like:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=12, tm_hour=16, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=102, tm_isdst=1)
printing again in 5 minutes
time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=12, tm_hour=16, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=102, tm_isdst=1)
printing again in 5 minutes
time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=12, tm_hour=16, tm_min=15, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=102, tm_isdst=1)
printing again in 5 minutes
...
```

Comment: sorry, i am not understanding this, are you able to show me using my code above? struggling on this alot